# JQMobile pageinit event fires before JQ document.ready

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am Developing a PhoneGap Application Which uses Jquery Mobile.
I want to customize my html dom's element before Jquery Mobile Initialize.
so I am writing this code in document.ready.
but for while now Jquery Mobile Initialize first and My document.ready code execute letter.
I cant figure how can this happen.

I have added .js files in this order.

1. JQ.js
2. myCode.js
3. JQM.js

Comment: Because JQM maybe be ready before your whole document is ready :) , if you need to call it after document ready call it as a function from document ready

Comment: Also you'll find the document ready is fired once - whereas pageinit gets fired every time you navigate. This is due to the ajax nature of JQM.

Comment: actually I want to manipulate dom element before JqueryMobile Initialize.

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap, dont use document.ready. Always write your JQM initialization code in DeviceReady event. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready.

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //call ur JQM init calls here
}

Comment: I want to manipulate my HTML's Dom Content before JQM initialization using Jquery. and thats the issue for me now.